# Calendar Events Displaying Wrongly

Tags: sync, calendar

I've added some events in Google Calendar in my web browser. These events occur every other week. In the web browser, the events are showed correctly as occurring every other week. However, in Android calendar (I'm using the stock calendar app), these events show up as events that occur every week.

Does anyone know what is wrong? I've tried clearing app data for Calendar and Calendar Storage, but the moment I set up sync again, the events get synced wrongly again, showing up as events that occur every week.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I managed to find out what the problem was.

Basically, these events were imported from an .ics file generated by a timetable builder website (I'm a university/college student, and the website builds your timetable for you if you key in the modules you take/plan to take). The classes that occur every alternate week are not saved as occurring every other week; they are saved as occurring every week, with exceptions of the dates of the alternate weeks.

I'm not sure if Google Calendar officially supports this as I see no option to save a repeating event with exceptions manually, but after importing the .ics file, these events show up fine in the web browser in Google Calendar. The calendar app on Android, however, does not recognise these exceptions, so they just show that the event occurs every week.